# Black Div with Opacity showing as Gray

Tags: css, opacity

I have a Div with a light background and a div inside that. I would like to give the background color of inner div a transparent black color(means i should be able to  see some of the light background of the parent Div). Would that be possible with CSS ?

I tried this but its not working, The div appears Gray and not transparent.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8L8DH/2/)

```
<div style="width: 600px height: 600px;background:#fcfcfc;position:relative; ">

    <div style="position:absolute;top:200px:left:200px;height:200px;width:200px;background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6); ">
    </div>
</div>
```

The opacity is working fine if i have a dark background.

Thanks !

Comment: It's grey, because it's got *white* showing through *black*; transparency is only evident if there's something visible to be seen *through/behind* the element that's got alpha-transparency; demo: http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/8L8DH/3/

Comment: So that means no way to achieve what i am trying to do ? I guess may be i was hoping to get a tinted black glass look, which i guess its not possible ! I was trying to put some images/words on the light background which could be seen through the transparent black background.

Comment: "I would like to give the background color of inner div a transparent black color" - But that's all working, the "grey" is exactly the 'transparent black color'. Be more objective about what is what you really want.

Comment: I updated my comment.. Hope my objective is clear.

Comment: Yes, for sure! but @DavidThomas have updated his comment as well, that isn't what you want to? If not, could you show us an example ?

Comment: This is one of those situations where an image would be worth a thousand (probably confusing words)...

Comment: Thank you all, I guess i will go for an Image like David suggested.I have upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the alpha channel using `opacity`. This is how it's done.

```
<div><div></div></div>

div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: yellow;
    position: relative;
}
div div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: gray;
    opacity: .5;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GZj75/